# CBOR diag. notation - express seqeunce of items

Tags: encoding, binary, cbor

I am wondering if it's possible to express just a plain sequence of concrete CBOR items in a given order, using CBOR diagnostic notation. By *plain*, I mean that I want to avoid using arrays for this; what I want, is stream semantics. For example:

> 1, "foo", true, simple(53), { a: "bar", x: 30 }, [1, 2, 3]

not this:

> [1, "foo", true, simple(53), { a: "bar", x: 30 }, [1, 2, 3]]

Moreover, is it also possible to do this with [CDDL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-cbor-cddl-00) (the schema definition language for CBOR)?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you wrote it? That is, what purpose do you have in mind that it doesn't suit? Keep in mind that the _diagnostic notation_ is only for diagnostics, i.e. debugging. It is explicitly **not for interchange**. Arguably it shouldn't even be in the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you are asking about.

No, it appears the diagnostic notation (as implemented at http://cbor.me) does not currently support a naked sequence of CBOR objects (not an  array), but yes the CBOR specification itself does permit it.

I guess this is a bug, but diagnostic notation isn't exactly a supported feature of CBOR.   You might get some responses by posting to the CBOR mailing list, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/group/cbor/about/ for the e-mail address, how to subscribe, and a searchable archive.

Comment: Thank you, I have come to the same conclusion. I am not already interested to the problem for now. But it would be interesting to get some sort of official answer (i.e. from CBOR mailing list).